# Need help on Python Decrementing

Tags: python

OK! I got this code that does not work properly, Here is the code:

```
def abDucks (a,b): 
while (a>1): 
print(a, "Little Ducks swimming in the sea") 
print("And if ",b," Little Ducks should accidentally drown") 
print("There'll be ", (a-b), "Little Ducks swimming in the sea\n") 
a=(a-b) 

if (a<=1): 
print(a, "Little Ducks swimming in the sea") 
print("And if ",b," Little Ducks should accidentally drown") 
print("There'll be no Little Ducks swimming in the sea\n")
```

The problem I have is that it counts to 0 and then it will print:
And if no little ducks should accidentally drown
There'll be no Little Ducks swimming in the sea

Please Help

I never did get an infinite loop lol :P
This is what happens when I run this code using (8,2)

> ```
> 8 Little Ducks swimming in the sea 
> And if 2 Little Ducks should accidentally drown 
> There'll be 6 Little Ducks swimming in the sea 
>
> 6 Little Ducks swimming in the sea 
> And if 2 Little Ducks should accidentally drown 
> There'll be 4 Little Ducks swimming in the sea 
>
> 4 Little Ducks swimming in the sea 
> And if 2 Little Ducks should accidentally drown 
> There'll be 2 Little Ducks swimming in the sea 
>
> 2 Little Ducks swimming in the sea 
> And if 2 Little Ducks should accidentally drown 
> There'll be 0 Little Ducks swimming in the sea 
>
> 0 Little Ducks swimming in the sea 
> And if 2 Little Ducks should accidentally drown 
> There'll be no Little Ducks swimming in the sea
> ```

Comment: Please edit the post with the correct indentation. Remember that indentation in Python is extremely important.

Comment: I rolled back the edit. Lynch, let OP do the indenting his or herself. We can make a really good guess, but I'd prefer to see what the *actual* indentation is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write the same code, succinctly, like this

```
def abDucks (a,b): 
    while (a - b >= 1):
        print(a, "Little Ducks swimming in the sea")
        print("And if ",b," Little Ducks should accidentally drown")
        print("There'll be ", (a-b), "Little Ducks swimming in the sea\n")
        a -= b
    else:
        print(a, "Little Ducks swimming in the sea")
        print("And if ",b," Little Ducks should accidentally drown")
        print("There'll be no Little Ducks swimming in the sea\n")
```

With this change, the output becomes

> ```
> 8 Little Ducks swimming in the sea
> And if  2  Little Ducks should accidentally drown
> There'll be  6 Little Ducks swimming in the sea
>
> 6 Little Ducks swimming in the sea
> And if  2  Little Ducks should accidentally drown
> There'll be  4 Little Ducks swimming in the sea
>
> 4 Little Ducks swimming in the sea
> And if  2  Little Ducks should accidentally drown
> There'll be  2 Little Ducks swimming in the sea
>
> 2 Little Ducks swimming in the sea
> And if  2  Little Ducks should accidentally drown
> There'll be no Little Ducks swimming in the sea
> ```

Comment: Thanks man, this really helped out a lot, Ive been trying to figure this out since yesterday and did not understand what was happening. Thank you so much!